# Reassign value of variable with javascript destructuring

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
const authReducer =(state= defaultState, action)=>{
    //const {email,firstname,lastname,phone,token} = action.data;
    switch(action.type){
        
        case 'LOGIN': 
        let {email,firstname,lastname,phone,token} = action.data;
        return {...state, email, firstname, lastname, phone, token, authenticated: true };

        case 'REGISTER':
        {email,firstname,lastname,phone,token} = action.data;
        return {...state, email, firstname, token, authenticated: true };

        case 'LOGOUT':
            return defaultState;

         default:
             return state;   
    }
}
```

Using the above code throws the error:

```js
 Parsing error: Unexpected token
```

Is there a way I can destructure action.data to declare the variable email, firstname, lastname... based on the switch cases?

If I try to declare the value before the switch block like this:

```js
/* ... */
const authReducer =(state= defaultState, action)=>{
    const {email,firstname,lastname,phone,token} = action.data;
    switch(action.type){

        case 'LOGIN': 
        //let {email,firstname,lastname,phone,token} = action.data;
        return {...state, email, firstname, lastname, phone, token, authenticated: true };

        case 'REGISTER':
        //{email,firstname,lastname,phone,token} = action.data;
        return {...state, email, firstname, token, authenticated: true };

        case 'LOGOUT':
            return defaultState;

         default:
             return state;   
    }
}

export default authReducer;
```

I get the error:

```js
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'email' of 'action.data' as it is undefined.
```

Comment: what's the data in action.data?

Comment: @HarshPatel action.data is only defined when i dispatch an action, it's by default undefined. So when my application run, it hits the error by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your first error: you are missing a declaration keyword in the `REGISTER` case:

```
case 'REGISTER':
        // {email,firstname,lastname,phone,token} = action.data;
        const {email,firstname,lastname,phone,token} = action.data;
```

Regarding your second error: for some actions the field `action.data` is not defined, hence you cannot deconstruct it. Stay with your first approach of deconstructing the action per case.

*** EDIT ***

```
const authReducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {

        case 'LOGIN': {
          const {email,firstname,lastname,phone,token} = action.data;
          return {...state, email, firstname, lastname, phone, token, authenticated: true };
        }

        case 'REGISTER': {
          const {email,firstname,lastname,phone,token} = action.data;
          return {...state, email, firstname, token, authenticated: true };
        }

        case 'LOGOUT':
            return defaultState;

         default:
             return state;   
    }
}
```

If you still see an error that `action.data` is not defined when you dispatch the `REGISTER` or `LOGIN` action, than the action itself does not poplate the data field properly (meaning that our assumptions about your action object is wrong..)

*** EDIT 2 ***

To answer your follow up question: The curley brackets in the case-statements do create additional scopes. Otherwise the scope of all variables is the `switch (...) {...}`-block. If you would define all cases in the same scope you could have collisions in variable names.

Comment: this throws the error: Parsing error: Identifier 'email' has already been declared... You will realize that I already declared a destructuring in the LOGIN case

Comment: you need to remove the decompose before the switch statement of course and only decompose it in the action.

Comment: I think I did this already. Could you please edit your answer just in case I am missing something. Also not that the action.data is by default undefined. It only get's defined when I dispatch an action

Comment: I added the foll reducer code and another note that we assume that the action creator corretly builds the action object by setting the `action.data` field in the `LOGIN` and `REGISTER` action.

Comment: Worked! I am surprised that the addition of "{}" in the LOGIN and REGISTER cases made such huge difference in the code execution.

Comment: I would really appreciate a reference to understand why the {} makes the difference or you could explain as well

Comment: I put some explanation regarding the scope (`{..}`) definitions as EDIT 2